# Validar um QLineEdit para só pegar Double

Tags: qt

Estou usando o `QDoubleValidator data = new QDoubleValidator(0.00, 1000.00, 2, lineEdit);`

Porém na hora de inserir o valor real no campo da `lineEdit` ele não recorre o ponto (`.`) como separador decimal e sim vírgula (`,`).

Isso ocasiona problemas na hora de pegar o valor digitado no campo porque o programa não pega nenhum valor com número usando vírgulas.

Como resolver esse problema deixando o ponto (`.`) como separador decimal?

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa definir o [`locale`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvalidator.html#setLocale) do `QDoubleValidator`:

```
auto validator = new QDoubleValidator(0, 1000.00, 2, lineEdit);
validator->setLocale(QLocale("pt_BR"));
lineEdit->setValidator(validator);
```

Observe que, por padrão, o Qt usa o locale do sistema. Se você usar o código acima pra fixar o locale, seu programa vai deixar de obedecer às preferências do usuário.